# I don't understand the mechanism of the JPA(Persistence Context)

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I found a strange phenomenon while testing the mechanism of the persistence context.

Member Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Member {
    protected Member() {}

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String username;

    public Member(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Service method

```
@Transactional
public void addMember(String username) {
    // create
    Member member = new Member(username);
    memberRepository.save(member);

    // read
    Member actual = memberRepository.findById(member.getId()).get();
    log.info("Same Entity ? : {}", member == actual);

    // update
    String newUsername = "kitty";
    member.setUsername(newUsername);
    memberRepository.save(member);

    // update verify
    actual = memberRepository.findById(member.getId()).get();
    log.info("Same Username ? : {}", member.getUsername().equals(actual.getUsername()));

    // delete
    memberRepository.delete(actual);
    actual = memberRepository.findById(member.getId()).orElse(null);
    log.info("Entity is null ? : {}", actual);
}
```

I think there is an entity on the PC(Persistence Context) before calling DELETE, and the DB also contains data.

When DELETE is called, FLUSH does not work immediately, so I understand that the DB still has data left, and it is removed from the PC(Persistence Context) after DELETE call.

And if you call findById again in that state, the PC(Persistence Context) does not have an entity, so you have to get it from DB.

Why is null returned from Actual?

Here is log

[IDE Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSChM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And if you call findById again in that state, the PC(Persistence
> Context) does not have an entity, so you have to get it from DB.

That depends on the `FlushModeType`. The default is `AUTO` and this means that Hibernate uses the PersistenceContext to get the Entitiy after the delete.

If you want to read it from the database you have to use `COMMIT`.

Example how to use it with a Query.

```
Member fromDB = em.createQuery("select m from Member m where m.id = :id", Member.class)
                  .setParameter("id", actual.getId())
                  .setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT)
                  .getSingleResult();
```

You can find everything about `FlushModeType.COMMIT` in the Hibernate documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#flushing-commit

Comment: Thank you for answers.

After reading the official document, I changed the FLUSH_MODE of Spring Boot to COMMIT, but it's still the same action. 

Is there a mechanism that is omitted when modifications and deletion are performed on the same entity in the hibernate?

Comment: Excerpt from Pro JPA 2nd Edition.

"As we discussed in Chapter 6, the persistence provider will attempt to minimize the number of times the persistence context must be flushed within a transaction. Optimally this will occur only once, when the transaction commits."

According to the above context, I assume that modifying and deleting the same entity in a transaction can occur optimization. Do you have any good references?

Comment: You can read this: https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/08/the-dark-side-of-hibernate-auto-flush.html

Comment: I don't know how to tell Spring Data JPA to use the FlushModeType but read my answer with an example by using a query

Comment: However, what is the reason for bringing in the changed value even though UPDATE did not occur?

Comment: That's how JPA works. You change data in the persistence context and get the changed data if you get the entity from the persistence context. It's the same as the database works There you have isolation levels like READ_COMMITED and REPETABLE_READ that are similar

Comment: Even if an explicit query is made to the DB using the JdbcTemplate, the changed value is obtained. If so, does JPA throw away the value and get the value from the PC(Persistence Context) even if it query in DB?

Comment: No that's not possible if no flush happend before. Show the code were you proof this

Comment: I mistook it for a query that reflected UPDATE by executing an incorrectly written JdbcTemplate code. Thank you for your kind response so far. It really helped me a lot.